# I am trying to build a Regex_Replace workaround to a long and often confusing Replace (Oracle12c)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

The select statement goes:

```
SELECT replace ( replace ( replace
( replace (table.ADDRESS,'Scarborough',' XXScarborough '),
     'North York','XXX York '),'Toronto','XXXToronto 
     '),'ON','NON ') as address,...
```

Comment: It won't be any simpler. REGEX allows you to search for several patterns in a single go (unlike REPLACE), but it still only allows you ONE replacement string; you can't direct it to replace each of four patterns with a corresponding (and different) replacement text.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt . Also, you should format your code in your question using the code formatting tools.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to store the pattern and replacement in an associative array, put it in  a [*with clause function*](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#functions). Though it ain't any shorter than your replace, it should definitely be less "confusing".

```
WITH FUNCTION my_replace (
    inp VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    v_out   VARCHAR2(1000) := inp;
    TYPE v_astype IS
        TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40) INDEX BY VARCHAR(40);
    v_pat      v_astype;
    v_idx      VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN
   v_pat('Scarborough') := (' XXScarborough ');
   v_pat('North York') := ('XXX York ');
   v_pat('Toronto') := ('XXXToronto ');
   v_pat('ON') := ('NON ');
    v_idx := v_pat.first;
    WHILE v_idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
        v_out := replace(v_out,v_idx,v_pat(v_idx) );
        v_idx := v_pat.next(v_idx);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN v_out;
END; 
SELECT my_replace(t.ADDRESS) --,other columns
 FROM mytable t;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e36b1bb4154b55bd7c30186bbf8dea4f)

Comment: Thank you ! Your response was useful. Also I stopped thinking "Regex replace" for my specific need in this case